# Can I downgrade OS X Lion via Migration Assisstant?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, downgrade, migration-assistant

I've been having a few little annoying issues with Lion that are irking me (choppy mouse, slow startup/shutdown, dead PowerPC apps).  Thinking of going back to Snow Leopard, I don't want to have to spend 10 hours reinstalling everything.

I am wondering if I can do a clean installation of Snow Leopard, and then migrate my data from my Lion Time Machine backup using the Migration Assistant.  I hope that this would just move my files, apps, settings, and users over into Snow Leopard from Lion.

Has anyone ever tried this? Is it wishful thinking?

Comment: Sure sounds like an interesting idea – I don't know if the migration assistant would allow it though. For a few ideas about migrating "manually", see here: [Migrate selected applications from a Time Machine backup](http://superuser.com/questions/334746/migrate-selected-applications-from-a-time-machine-backup/334753#334753)

Comment: @roybatty - "dead PowerPC apps" - this is because they removed the feature that allowed this from Lion.

Comment: @Ramhound - yeah, i was aware of this when i upgraded and didn't think it would be a big deal.  then i just kept saying to myself - "oh, this doesn't work too?" :)

Comment: @slhck - thanks for that info.  i may just give this a try over the weekend.  if it doesn't work I can just do a full restore to lion from my time machine backup and make due.  i'll post my results here.

Comment: Any news on how it went? I'm thinking of doing the same, as even with the latest 27" iMac and 16GB RAM, Aperture is unusable under Lion, and worked lightening-fast under Snow Leopard.

Comment: popped in the snow leopard install disc and got this message when trying to run the installer.

**You can't use this version of the application Install Mac OS X with this version of Mac OS X.

You have Install Mac OS X 23.1.**

:(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i was able to run the SL installer by booting from the disc directly via startup disk (duh).  I ran into a few issues and it was a bit of a headache.  See below...

- SL would not install over my disk that had lion on it already - had to wipe it first.  After wiping it installed fine.
- On first boot after install, I chose to migrate from another mac and chose my TM backup of lion and checked all options when selecting what to migrate
- After items migrated, the system rebooted and brought me to the login screen for my migrated user, but **MY PASSWORD DID NOT WORK** (odd), so I had to boot to the SL disc again and use the Password Reset Utility
- Upon reboot, my system got stuck at the grey startup screen with the grey loading indicator and the circle slash icon in place of the apple icon.  Booting into safe mode fixed this.
- Finally I was able to boot properly and login to SL with all my apps and settings intact!!
- BUT, after running software update for 10.6.8, the mac got stuck on a blue screen after install & wouldn't shut down.
- forced a restart, and the system got stuck at a blue screen again after the grey apple & loading icon.
- after a bit of research on how to resolve the blue screen issue, i restarted AGAIN into safe mode and downloaded the combo update directly from apple.  ran the installer from the dmg and WENT TO BED.

Later today I'm going to check it again to see if the update went well.  Hopefully i'm good after all of this.  Gotta say that I can't recommend this process with the amount of issues i ran into.

Comment: could not get past the blue screen @ startup.  put lion back.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this - do the flatten and install as before, but create a separate "Admin" account when you install. Once the machine is up, re-create your user account, and select that you want to recover the user from the Time Machine backup of the machine. That should pull in just the stuff for your user account, without restoring anything outside your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to improve Mac lion performance. You can speed up Lion startup and other speed related issues with Stellar speed up Mac. This tool is an excellent remedy for speed related hurdles for Lion and other previous versions of Mac.

Basically its a Mac optimization tool which enhances the OS read/ write operation.